# How to display data on mobile app screen?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a music app for one of my school projects. So it requires the app to be able to read the storage of the phone and then display it.

So far I'm able to read the storage for songs and its data by using MediaStore (Code at the bottom). From there, I store the required data into `Song` class like this:

```
Song(String _songName, String _songArtist, String _songAlbum, String _songUri, String _coverArt).
```

After the data is stored into the class, I then store it into an `ArrayList`.

Hence, I'm able to read the data and store. But from there I'm not too sure on how to display it from the list that I have stored it in.

```
private void loadSongs() {
    Uri audioUri =  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(audioUri, null, null, null, null);
    if(audioCursor != null) {
        if(audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String songName = audioCursor.getString(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String songArtist = audioCursor.getString(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String songAlbum = audioCursor.getString(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                String songUri = audioCursor.getString(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                Song newSong = new Song(songName, songArtist, songAlbum, songUri, null);

                loadedSong.add(newSong);

            } while(audioCursor.moveToNext());

        }
        audioCursor.close();
    }
}

private void loadPictures() {
    Uri imageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, null, null, null, null);
    if(imageCursor != null) {
        if(imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String pictureAlbum = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE));
                String pictureUri = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

                CoverArt newCoverArt = new CoverArt(pictureAlbum, pictureUri);

                loadedCoverArt.add(newCoverArt);

            } while(imageCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        imageCursor.close();
    }
}

private void arrangeCoverArt() {
    for(int audioStart = 0; audioStart < (loadedSong.size() - 1); audioStart++) {
        Song currentSong = loadedSong.get(audioStart);
        String audioUri = currentSong.getSongUri();
        String[] arrayAudioUri = audioUri.split("/");
        for(int coverStart = 0; coverStart < (loadedCoverArt.size() - 1); coverStart++) {
            CoverArt currentCover = loadedCoverArt.get(coverStart);
            String coverUri = currentCover.getCoverArtUri();
            String[] arrayCoverUri = coverUri.split("/");
            if(arrayAudioUri[(arrayAudioUri.length - 2)].equals(arrayCoverUri[(arrayCoverUri.length - 2)])) {
                currentSong.setCoverArt(currentCover.getCoverArtUri());
                displayedData.add(currentSong.getSongName() + "\n" + currentSong.getSongArtist() + "\n" + currentSong.getSongAlbum() + "\n" + currentSong.getCoverArt());
                break;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

How I want to display the songs:

[image]

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: Use TextView widget to display something on android screen. And make sure you add particular code for your question please.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is not clear. Are you asking how to display text? Display a list? Both?

Comment: How do you store the songs (what data structure? `List`, `Map`?)? Do you have a custom class for that or do you just want to display the paths or names?

Comment: is there a way to bump this question up?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches for this problem and it really depends on what you are trying to solve. For example if you want to show them all in one place you could use `ListView` or you want to show only one music at a time -like Spotify- you should consider to design and implement a standalone view that takes those variables as parameter and show them to user.